# How to get selected radio button telerik?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

I have html code like this

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="rdYes" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" ButtonType="ToggleButton"
       CssClass="rdYes" Text="" ToggleType="Radio" GroupName="HolderGroup" BorderStyle="None">
</telerik:RadButton>Yes

<telerik:RadButton ID="rdNo" runat="server" AutoPostBack="False" ButtonType="ToggleButton"
CssClass="rdNo" Text="" ToggleType="Radio" GroupName="HolderGroup" BorderStyle="None">
</telerik:RadButton>No
```

I have tried to use javascript to get the selected radio button with the following code, but it isn't working. Is there a better way to do this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".parent1").css("display", "none");

            if ($('#<%= rdYes.ClientID %>').checked) (function () {
                alert('Test Get Radio Yes');
                $(".parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
            });
            else if ($('#<%= rdNo.ClientID %>').checked) (function () {
                alert('Test Get Radio No');
                $(".parent1").slideUp("fast"); //Slide Up Effect
            });
        });
</script>
```

**Thanks for advance**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the Telerik client side api http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-client-side-basics.html

```
var button = $find("<%= rdYes.ClientID%>");
if(button.get_checked())
{
     alert("is checked");
}
```